# Create crowdsale contract with newer version solidity of token contract

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

I have created token contract with solidity ver. ^0.8.0 and now I want create crowdsale contract.

1. Is there a way to combine crowdsale contract (solidity version 0.8.0) with token contract crowdsale (pragma 0.5.0) ?

When compiling using pragma as below

> pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <=0.8.0;

getting error from older contract cuz for newer compiler some functions are wrote in wrong way.

2. I was thinking to write crowdsale contract with solidity ver. 0.8.0 because openzeppelin doesn't offer in newest version of their contracts. It's just I'm worrying about security. I was also considering to write token contract with older solidity version (same as crowdsale contract which is 0.5.0 version), just don't know what's option is better? (for security reason) Any of you guys tried to write crowdsale contract with newer version of solidity than 0.5.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about security at all, is just not compatible because a lot changed between versions and maintain the crowdsale smart contracts is complicated and takes to much time.

> Due to both a decline in their usage and the complexity associated
> with migrating them to Solidity v0.6.

So you need to develop your own smart contracts.